# PowerShell hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object Name, @{n="Hash";e={Get-FileHash \\$_.Name\netlogon\site\logon.bat}}
```

Output

```
Name      Hash
----      ----
DC001
DC002
```

Any ideas why this isn't working.  It's been a while since I used a hash table to pull information like this, so I must be missing something minor.  I have also tried to just return the name, Get-Childitem, which doesn't work.  I have also tried just $_.Name, which does work and returns a string.

I am trying to verify the file exists and is the same on all DCs.

Comment: `Get-FileHash "\\$($_.Name)\netlogon\site\logon.bat"`. The quotes aren't technically necessary in this case but I do think they clarify that we're using string interpolation.

Comment: In short: Only variables _by themselves_ can be embedded as-is in expandable strings (`"..."`) (which command arguments situationally _implicitly_ are), e.g. `"foo/$var"` or `"foo/$env:USERNAME"`. To embed _expressions_ or even commands, you must enclose them in `$(...)`. Notably, this includes property and indexed access (e.g., `"foo/$($var.property)"`, `"foo/$($var[0])"`). See the linked duplicate for details.